# Embedded Tomcat without unpacking

Tags: spring-mvc, java-7, executable-jar, embedded-tomcat-7

What steps are required to make a executable war without unpacking the war. ( Similar to the way spring boot does). Basically want to wrap Embedded Tomcat into existing war and make it execurable.

Env: Spring mvc, Java 7, Webapp with web.xml

So far I have done following research:

1. How Spring boot creates Embedded container in TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory, but all those WebApploader stuff I'm not able to understsnd.
2. Successfull in packaging a executable war just using spring boot maven plugin but not able to run without unpacking it.
3. Tomcat api class doesn't read app from war directly.
4. Have successfully tested embedded tomcat by extracting it in a particular location and calling addWebapp method.
5. I do not want to create a big fat jar using shade plugin.
6. Do not want to specify path like src/main as indicated on many examples on the internet.
7. Upgrading the app to spring boot web is not possible due to time and other dependencies.